# Python (PyMySQL) SELECT query returning boolean, not desired value

Tags: python, pymysql

I am using PyMySQL with Python to access my database. (MySQLdb is not yet available for newer releases of Python.)

This is my query:

```
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT ingredientID FROM Ingredients WHERE ingredientName = %s", "onions")
```

However, instead of returning the `ingredientID`, a boolean is returned stating the recipe was found. I have worked with MySQL(i) in PHP and have not had this issue occur in the past.

Comment: If by "boolean" you mean "byte literal" then this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27855037/pymysql-connection-select-query-and-fetchall-return-tuple-that-has-byte-literals/27873654#27873654

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to somehow fetch the result of the query:

```
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT ingredientID FROM Ingredients WHERE ingredientName = %s", "onions")
print(cur.fetchone()) # Fetch one row
```

or

```
print(cur.fetchall()) # Fetch all rows
```

Comment: Thx! this works. My only question is how do I pull the value from the tuple that is created?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940670/pymysql-fetchall-results-as-dictionary) explains how to do it

Comment: Thanks again, right before you responded, I realized I could just use the fetchone() itself.