# pandas :Read xlsx file to dict with column1 as key and column2 as values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, xlsx

I am new to pandas. I need to read a `xlsx` file and convert first column to key of a dict and second column to values of a dict using `pandas`. I also need to skip / exclude first row which are headers.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531142/how-to-get-a-dictionary-of-data-in-column1-as-key-and-column2-as-the-value) is for `pymysql` and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870022/read-two-column-csv-as-dict-with-1st-column-as-key) is for `csv`. I need to user `pandas`.

Here is a sample excel data

```
dict_key    dict_value  
key1        str_value1  
key2        str_value2  
key3         None  
key4         int_value3
```

My code so far is as below.

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = "file.xlsx"
xls = pd.ExcelFile(excel_file)
df = xls.parse(xls.sheet_names[0], skiprows=1, index_col=None, na_values=['None'])
data_dict = df.to_dict()
```

However, it gives me dict where keys are column numbers and values are both column1 data as well as column2 data.

```
>>> data_dict
{u'Chg_Parms': {0: u'  key1 ', 1: u'   key2 ', 2: u'   key3 ', 3: u'   key4 ', 4: u'   str_value1 ', 
                5: u'   str_value2 ', 6: u'   Nan ', 6: u'   int_value3 '}}
```

what I would like to have is column1 data as key and column two data as values and also `NaN` replaced with `None`

```
data_dict = {'key1': 'str_value1', 'key2': 'str_value2', 'key3': None, 'key4': int_value3}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to keep the keys in order. You'll note that [`pd.read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) loads the first sheet by default. Edit: then you say you want to encode the items in the dictionary, and evaluate `'None'` as `None`...

```
import collections as co
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
od = co.OrderedDict((k.strip().encode('utf8'),v.strip().encode('utf8')) 
                    for (k,v) in df.values)
```

Result:

```
>>> od
OrderedDict([(u'key1', u'str_value1'), (u'key2', u'str_value2'), (u'key3', u'None'), (u'key4', u'int_value3')])
```

General note: you should keep strings as Unicode within your Python program.

Comment: @ bernie Thanks for the ans. This is definitely towards what I need. However, how do I convert each key value to non unicode representation, strip white space and also maintain its type. for eg. str(u' 1')  results in '1'  and str(u'None')  results in 'None'. I need `int` and `boolean` values as it is.

Comment: @Anil_M: you're very welcome. Please see edited answer.

Comment: I added .strip() next to encode('utf8') to take care of white space. I belive that answers my questions. thanks.

Comment: @Anil_M: anytime! Happy coding to you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas [read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) method to read the excel file more conveniently. You can pass a index_col argument where you can define which column of your xlsx is the index.

How to change NaN to None is explained in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162723/replacing-pandas-or-numpy-nan-with-a-none-to-use-with-mysqldb).

Given an xlsx file called example.xlsx which is build like you wrote above, the following code should give your expected results:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("example.xlsx", index_col=0)
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)

print df.to_dict()["dict_value"]
```

Comment: `df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)` nice one, +1