# AWS Lambda output format - JSON

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I trying to format my output from a lambda function into JSON. The lambda function queries my Amazon Aurora RDS instance and returns an array of rows in the following format:

- [[name,age,town,postcode]]

which gives the an example output:

- [["James", 23, "Maidenhead","sl72qw"]]

I understand that mapping templates are designed to translate one format to another but I don't understand how I can take the output above and map in to a JSON format using these mapping templates.

I have checked the documentation and it only covers converting one JSON to another.

Comment: What language are you using in lambda? Javascript? Python? Java? What are you using to pull the data out of Amazon Aurora? I suspect that you're pulling the data out without using a required parameter that'll give you an associative array instead of a numeric array, but you haven't supplied enough information to tell.

Comment: I am using Python in Lambda. I am using the pymysql module to get the data from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the code you're specifically using, it's difficult to give you a definitely correct answer, but I suspect what you're after is returning the data from python as a dictionary then converting that to JSON.

It looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940670/pymysql-fetchall-results-as-dictionary) thread contains the relevant details on how to do that.

More specifically, using the DictCursor

```
cursor = connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```